# Zend Framework in subdirectory

Tags: zend-framework, dns, subdirectory, base-url

I'm banging over the wall with this...

I need to establish a zend framework application inside a subdirectory.

i.e. the domain is tricell.ss and I want to use tricell.ss/tricell as application main directory.

Whate've done:

1. I've setted up in my config (application.ini) the:

   ```
   resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/tricell"
   ```
2. I've made another var in my config

   ```
   baseUrl  = "/tricell"
   ```
3. In my Boostrap I've got this:

   ```
   $router     = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
   $frontController->setRouter($router);
   $frontController->setBaseUrl($this->config->baseUrl);        

   $frontController->dispatch();
   ```
4. In my layout I'm trying to display image with using:

   ```
   $this->baseUrl('/img/btn.png')
   ```
5. Here are my vhost configuration:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/public_html"
   ServerName tricell.ss
   RewriteRule ^$ [L] 

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?tricell.ss$
   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ tricell [L]
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. here is my .htaccess:

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is when I'm trying to display image nothing happens. When I'm trying to get the image by URL:

http://tricell.ss//tricell/img/btn.png

I'm getting info about wrong controller. How I can make this right? I can (without any problems) make configuration for root domain like tricell.ss and then get image i.e. tricell/ss/img/btn.png, but I want to work on subdirectory, and I can't do that with images. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just manage to resolve my issue... it's quite simple but I was very confused by all this rewriting rules.

As saying always tricell is confusing let's make some changes to that as well.
So to achive something like tricell.ss/sub I would need to:

1. Put my whole application inside /HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/sub
2. Change my vhost from this line: DocumentRoot "/HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/public_html" to: DocumentRoot "/HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/"
3. Insert yet another .htaccess in my /HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/sub directory:

   RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /sub/ublic_html/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/public_html/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/public_html/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public_html/.*$ /sub/public_html/index.php [NC,L]

This resolved my all issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing you can do to get this working is this:

Start with a fresh ZF project, or remove all of your zend routes, and any special configuration in .htaccess or httpd.conf/httpd-vhosts.conf that you created.

Get rid of the baseUrl options you set up in your config file.

Place the index.php file and the .htaccess file in your `/HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/public_html/tricell` folder.

Place the rest of your project (controllers, models, config etc) outside of your web root.  In this example I will assume they are placed in `/HTDOCS/tricell/tricell/zfproject`.

Edit index.php and change:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// to:

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../zfproject/application'));
```

Now your application will run with the base directory being yoursite.com/tricell

IndexController.php's URL is going to be http://yoursite.com/tricell/index

You do not need to do anything special to tell Zend your base URL is "tricell".  Just make sure in your view scripts to use `$this->baseUrl()` for your paths so you don't need to worry about manually adding /tricell to the beginning of everything, and if you ever move your project to another directory/path, nothing needs to be changed to deal with the new paths.

Comment: If I'm not changing any vhost I think I need an additional .htaccess in public_html, correct me if I'm wrong. Unfortunatly your solution doesn't work. I've got a 404 screen when entering: domain.local/tricell/index

Comment: You don't have to have any special .htaccess file in public_html, only the Zend Framework .htaccess and index.php in public_html/tricell.  You should also put your assets such as images and css in public_html/tricell also.  All we are changing with index.php is the fact that the core application doesn't live one level up from your public directory.  In this case it is 2 levels up in its own folder.  I was able to get this setup to work on my site and only had to change index.php where it defines APPLICATION_PATH.  Let me know how its going

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/tour/"
 RewriteRule (.*) /tour/index.php [L,END]
</IfModule>
```

The above code in the root folder domain.com/.htaccess worked for me. I placed it directly as the first thing in the htaccess before the "# BEGIN WordPress" parts.

- having a Zend installation in the domain.com/tour/ subdirectory
- wordpress running on the root domain.com/ level

The final knack was to have the RewriteRule point to the index.php of Zend if Request_URI matches /tour/